# PHP list of keys => values

Tags: php, mysql

this is my first topic on this site; I'm a newbie just starting with PHP.

I saw that my question has been asked and answered several times; I think to have read almost all of them, but I did not find the final response.

I need to send from PHP (V. 5.5) a result from a MySQL query to a JQuery function.
It is important to me that the sent text string is in the form: FieldName=FieldValue

I tried most of the suggestion found on this site, but actually I get a double entry for each field, which are 'Index:keyname'. In other words, each field is sent twice, and the value associated with the fied is missing.

The last test was performed with this code:

```
foreach(array_keys($row) as $key => $valore) {
  echo ($key." --> value= ".$valore."<br/>");
}
```

What I actually receive is:

```
0 --> value= 0  
1 --> value= IDcomponent  
2 --> value= 1  
3 --> value= IDtype  
4 --> value= 2  
5 --> value= Manufacturer
....
```

while I would need instead:

```
IDcomponent = 100  
IDtype= 5  
Manufacturer = Texas  
...
```

With this alternate code:

```
$fields=mysql_num_fields($result);

for ($ix=0; $ix<$fields; $ix++) {
  $ky = $row[$ix];
  echo ($ky." = ".key($ky)."<br>"); 
}
```

I get (in example):

```
100 =  
5 =  
Texas =
```

The key name is empty.

I hope this is clear enough; sorry for any error.

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks

Comment: `$ky` contains an integer/string and nothing else, meaning it does not have a key, so `key($ky)` does not work.

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for:

```
foreach($row as $key => $valore) {
    echo ($key." --> value= ".$valore."<br/>");
}
```

With `array_keys()` you are only looping over an array of the array_keys.

Comment: Thanks @Tobias; actually I also tried your code before, but I got twice the same string as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Tobias; I previously tried your code, but I still got twice the same string in answer.

Actually I solved my stupid problem with a workaround.
The solution is use the same code you suggested followed by an IF to test for odd/even lines and then send only the odd ones. Brutal, but it does the job, waiting to understand what I did wrong.

```
$cnt=0;
foreach($row as $key=>$value)
{
  if (($cnt & 1))
  echo $key."|".$value."§";
  $cnt++;
}
```

Thanks to @treegarden too who gave me an interesting hint to investigate.